# Android chathead floating activity

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the chatHeads from facebook. This part is working.

I want it to behave similarly to facebooks chatheads. When you tap the bubble it shows a view and tapping again closes the view.

So far my problem is deciding what this view should be.

I am trying to accomplish it through the following.

I decided to use a floating activity since i think it would provide the most flexibility.

Is this the right way to do this. In the end i would like to stick a view pager in there.

```
public class BubbleOverlay extends Activity {

private boolean active = false;
private View mainView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.overlay_layout);
    mainView = findViewById(R.id.main_overlay_layout);
}

public void setActive(boolean value){
    active = value;
}

public void hide(){
    active = false;
    mainView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

public void show(){
    active = true;
    mainView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public boolean getActive(){
    return this.active;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    active = true;
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    active = false;
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    active = false;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

The Chathead is implements and toggles the activity like so:

```
        overlay = new BubbleOverlay();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, overlay.getClass()).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable_longClick = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            overlay.hide();
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable_longClick, 5000);
```

This crashes on on the following error:

```
07-24 01:27:33.195 4752-4752/com.some.package E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: com.some.package, PID: 4752
                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                    at com.some.package.BubbleOverlay.hide(BubbleOverlay.java:34)
                                                                    at com.some.package.BubbleService$5.run(BubbleService.java:170)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6044)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a project by mollyIV who already implemented it:

https://github.com/mollyIV/ChatHeads

it should help you